# What are some things to keep in mind when building e-commerce sites?

Tags: php, mysql, architecture, e-commerce

In the coming months, I will be tasked with creating an e-commerce site for the first time. I've worked with e-commerce sites before, making edits and themes but never made one from the bottom up.

I know this isn't a small undertaking which is why i'm doing research now!

- What are somethings that i would only learn from experience?
- What options do i have when it comes to the payment side of the site?
- Any architecture tips?

This will be done in php/mysql

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read this thread

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site

Comment: Thanks, it's a great thread. But i'm looking for information that is more ecommerce specific.

Comment: The linked thread seems to cover most things in general already. You may want to revise your question to be more specific if you want a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Credit card processing is a huge gottcha - It can cost heaps if you don't get it right, and it can cost even more if you give up and farm the processing out to someone else at huge transaction fee %ages.

Also, there are a tonne of decent open source / cheap options in PHP (as well as in C# and JEE). My company actually bought a small company that had done a souped-up version of an open-source version of an eCommerce store.

Finally, keep a really good eye on master-data. This can screw you if you end up tracking customers and sales items in different ways than you track them in other system. In my case, this meant very expensive integration with our CRM, Identity, and Sales systems.